# favicon.ico being rendered as part of query parameter; probable route issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes

In localhost / WEBrick configuration (Rails 3.1, ruby 1.9.2, one of my routes takes the favicon.ico file as a request parameter. It seems to be only on this one route and am not sure sure why it is doing this:

In my routes:
routes.rb

```
scope '/arc' do 
  match '/item/:id' => 'items#show', :as => :item_show  # id can be either integer or text 
end
```

In html:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /> 

Started GET "/arc/item/test-306-some-item" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-18 12:18:18 -0700
```

...
why is it doing this??? only on the above route?

```
Started GET "/arc/item/favicon.ico" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-18 12:18:22 -0700
Creating scope :page. Overwriting existing method Item.page.
  Processing by ItemsController#show as 
  Parameters: {"id"=>"favicon"}
```

Any ideas on why it would be doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use absolute URI `/favicon.ico` and then it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the full path of the favicon

Like

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

In order to work in all environment like development and production you can use Rails tag for this

```
<%= favicon_link_tag "favicon.ico" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="<%= image_path("favicon.png") %>" />
```